# How do you get Memoria?

Tags: dissidia-final-fantasy-nt

In *Dissidia Final Fantasy NT*, you need Memoria to unlock the story. How do you get Memoria?

Answer (score 1):

**You Must Slay Your Enemies!**

The way to unlock a Memoria is to *win online battles* (Slay your enemies!).  When you *level up* you will receive Memoria.  If you are interested in unlocking all the cutscenes (in the "Story Tab") then you have to keep playing online battles.  Picking a good character can have significant impact on how fast you level, meaning how fast you collect Memoria, so experiment with characters to find a good one!

Comment: Thanks. I think i'm best with Cloud. If you wanna friend me on PS to help me my PS name is RaineMPhillips

Comment: @YouTube-RaineFall, glad to help.  If this answered your question consider hitting the checkmark.